# Configure FreeRADIUS to only support EAP TTLS PAP

Tags: freeradius

I have an external RADIUS server that only supports PAP. I have configured FreeRADIUS 2.2.4 to proxy the PAP request inside an EAP-TTLS tunnel (from a WiFi access point configured for WPA2 Enterprise) to this RADIUS server, and I tested it with eapol_test. I can manually configure a PC or Mac to only send EAP-TTLS+PAP but this is not really desirable.

When unconfigured WPA2 Enterprise clients connect they try PEAP and LEAP and EAP-MD5. I disabled most of the other EAP types, but it seems that I need at least one other EAP type supported in `default_eap_type` in the TTLS block. The non-commented part of my eap.conf is below:

```
eap {
    default_eap_type = ttls
    timer_expire     = 60
    ignore_unknown_eap_types = no
    cisco_accounting_username_bug = no
    max_sessions = 4096
    md5 {
    }
    tls {
        certdir = ${confdir}/certs
        cadir = ${confdir}/certs

        private_key_password = heythatsprivate
        private_key_file = ${certdir}/server.pem
        certificate_file = ${certdir}/server.pem
        dh_file = ${certdir}/dh
        random_file = /dev/urandom
        CA_path = ${cadir}
        cipher_list = "DEFAULT"
        make_cert_command = "${certdir}/bootstrap"
        ecdh_curve = "prime256v1"
        cache {
              enable = yes
              lifetime = 24 # hours
              max_entries = 255
        }
        verify {
        }
        ocsp {
              enable = no
              override_cert_url = yes
              url = "http://127.0.0.1/ocsp/"
        }
    }
    ttls {
        default_eap_type = md5 
        copy_request_to_tunnel = no
        use_tunneled_reply = no
        virtual_server = "inner-tunnel"
    }
}
```

Is there a way to configure FreeRADIUS so that there are no EAP types allowed inside TTLS or to explicitly require PAP inside the tunnel?

Thanks,
-rohan

Answer (score 0):

Try to setup a new servers besides the default...

```
server my-server {
   authorize { ... }

   authenticate { 
       eap
   }

   accounting { ... }
}
```

Then create a inner-tunnel for second fase of authentication

```
server my-tunnel {
     authorize {
          pap
     }
     ...
     authenticate {
         Auth-Type PAP {
            pap
         }
     }
     ...
}
```

You will need to modify your EAP configuration as this:

```
eap {
            default_eap_type = ttls
            ...

            ttls {
                    default_eap_type = gtc
                    copy_request_to_tunnel = yes
                    use_tunneled_reply = yes
                    virtual_server = "my-tunnel"
            }
            ...
     }
```

Then specify for each client what server do you want to use to process authentication requests

```
client example {
    ipv6addr       = x.x.x.x
    netmask        = 32
    secret         = *******
    shortname      = example
    virtual_server = my-server
}
```

I'm sure this will enable what do you want to do.

Regards,

-Hernan Garcia

Comment: Hi Hernan,
I tried this and it did not work. Maybe I wasn't 100% clear on what I am trying to do. I want to do only EAP-TTLS/PAP (not EAP-GTC). This works when I use eapol_test and explicitly send EAP-TTLS/PAP, but I need help negotiating the valid auth types. I want only EAP-TTLS in the DEFAULT virtual-server and only accept PAP in the inner-tunnel. All PAP requests in the inner-tunnel get forwarded to an external server. If the RADIUS client proposes MS-CHAPv2 in the inner-tunnel I want the magic unlang special sauce to NAK the request and ask for only PAP.  
Any ideas?
Thanks,
-rohan

Comment: @RohanMahy I know it's been a while, but did you find a solution?